# Order by one to many FK in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a class with a list that stores a list of dates for an event, and I need to query for the list of events and order them by the dates, how can I achieve this in Entity Framework.

This is my main class

```
public class UserEv
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Dates> dates { get; set; }
}
```

I need to query for the dates available in this class

```
public class Dates
{
    public DateTime start { get; set; }
    public DateTime end { get; set; }
}
```

I need to order the results that I get from the query by the start date. How can I achieve this in EF.This is the current query I use to get the data from the db, I am having trouble on the ordering part.

```
db.UserEv.Where(l=> l.dates.Any(a => a.start>= (start)))
         .Where(l=> l.dates.Any(b => b.end<= (end)))
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: why don't you use orderby?

Comment: @prhmma I did try order by but it says the ordey by has to be a comparable with an key.this is the code i used for that db.UserEv.Where(l=> l.dates.Any(a => a.start>= (start)))
         .Where(l=> l.dates.Any(b => b.end<= (end))).OrderBy(l => l.dates)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this works:

```
db.UserEv.Where(l=> l.dates.Any(a => a.start>= (start)))
     .Where(l=> l.dates.Any(b => b.end<= (end)))
```

To sort by the earliest start date:

```
.OrderBy(l => l.Dates.Min(d => d.start));
```